# Create Html Table Using YII Framework

Tags: php, yii

I am just new to YII framework and know very basics of YII like CRUD etc.
I just want to create HTML Tables using YII. Following is mine VIEW code where I rendered an array `$results` and it contains all records that I want to be shown using HTML Table

```
    <?php
/* @var $this RrCimyUefDataController */
/* @var $model RrCimyUefData */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Rr Cimy Uef Datas'=>array('index'),
    'Create',

);
?>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Serial Number</th>
  <th>Business Name</th>
  <th>Facebook</th>
  <th>Twitter</th>
</tr>


<?php
for($a=0, $b=1;$a<count($results);$a=$a+3,$b++){
    if(($a+1)<count($results) && ($a+2)<count($results)){
echo '<tr><td>'.$b.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$results[$a].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$results[$a+1].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$results[$a+2].'</td></tr>';
}
}
//var_dump($results);
?>
</table>
```

The code is working fine but it is not done through proper YII methods.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) and [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) for rendering grid, but it will give you some additional functionality, there is no helper that just renders simple table in Yii. Also you can use

```
echo CHtml::openTag('table');
echo CHtml::openTag('tr');
echo CHtml::tag('th', array(), 'Serial Number'); // for hable head
...
echo CHtml::closeTag('tr');

echo CHtml::openTag('tr');
echo CHtml::tag('td', array(), $results[$a+1]); // for cells
echo CHtml::closeTag('tr');
```

If you want.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me alot, although your code is not 100% but it gave me a guide.. Thanks again :)

Comment: Angle brackets not required in tag function calls.